# Delete other app data(not my app) in Android

Tags: android, appdata

I tried to search for an hour but I could not find how to do this.
I found a lot of information about how to delete own app data but it seems hard to find the way how to delete "other" app data.

Let's assume, I know all required information about target app.
And you can assume phone is rooted if necessary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you want to delete from:

```
/data/data/<packagename>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10850154)

Comment: @mozarty where do you see a link?

Comment: @ligi This is an automated reply from the review system. Probably mozarty means that your answer is very short and could be extended a bit in order to make it more useful. Which commands to use or if the data is always only at that location and what exactly packagename is and how packagename relates to the app name.... maybe.